# Dplyr arrange in Power BI with R not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, powerbi

Want to use dplyr to sort my dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

In R Studio

```
arrange(mtcars, mpg)
```

works just fine

In Power BI

```
arrange(dataset, Order)
```

Does not work. "Order" is a column with numbers 1-100. I'm, expecting R dplyr to order the column numerically in ascending order. When I apply this bit of code, my visual doesn't break but it also doesn't do anything. I.e. nothing moves or changes. I've also tried another column "Productline" with the same results.

I even tried going a little overboard by explicitly calling a local data.frame with tibble and then calling dplyr again. Still is not working.

```
#Tibble
dataset <- tbl_df(dataset)
as.data.frame(dataset)

#Dplyr stuff
arrange(dataset, Productline)
```

What am I missing here? Why does dplyr work just fine in R Studio but not in Power BI (other libraries work fine - scales and ggplot2). Something wrong about the way my dataset is created? Something strange with Power BI? Yes, R studio and Power BI are using the same directory (and as added fodder, other libraries work fine).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? For example, what's the output of `str(dataset)`?

Comment: @nachocab I'll admit I have a hard time understanding how to share a reproducible example. I would have to create a fake dataset (or something) bc the real data should not be out on the web.

Comment: Yeah, you could make a smaller version with fake data that still gives you the same problem and that you'd be ok sharing online